# SQL View - slow results from EF - much faster with manual query in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework-6

I have a Database First EF 6 ASP.Net application.  I am using SQL Server Express and I am having a problem with accessing the results from a particular view, using Entity Framework.

The code generated by EF takes around 5,000 milliseconds to fetch the results.

The same code in a manual query within SSMS takes around 400ms.

The view returns 480,000 results in its raw form (a list of product prices for all clients).

After some research, I found that it may have been Implicit Conversion as I was searching on a string.  I added the following code in my class:

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string ProductCompound { get; set; }
```

This unfortunately did not make any difference.

The code I have in my EF .Net app is:

```
//Fetch current price for this client
activeRatecardPrice = cckentities.vClientActiveRatecardPrices.Where(p => 
p.ClientId == clientId && p.ProductCompound == 
productCompound).FirstOrDefault();
```

The SQL output by this is as follows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[AutoId] AS [AutoId], 
[Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Extent1].[ProductCompound] AS [ProductCompound], 
[Extent1].[ProductRatecardGroupId] AS [ProductRatecardGroupId], 
[Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
[Extent1].[RatecardId] AS [RatecardId], 
[Extent1].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
[Extent1].[RatecardName] AS [RatecardName], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[VariationName] AS [VariationName], 
[Extent1].[InternalCode] AS [InternalCode], 
[Extent1].[ManufacturerProductCode] AS [ManufacturerProductCode], 
[Extent1].[ManufacturerName] AS [ManufacturerName], 
[Extent1].[Ean] AS [Ean], 
[Extent1].[ClientName] AS [ClientName], 
[Extent1].[AccountCode] AS [AccountCode], 
[Extent1].[ProductCategoryName] AS [ProductCategoryName], 
[Extent1].[ProductRatecardGroupName] AS [ProductRatecardGroupName]
FROM (SELECT 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[AutoId] AS [AutoId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductCompound] AS [ProductCompound], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductRatecardGroupId] AS 
[ProductRatecardGroupId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[Name] AS [Name], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[VariationName] AS [VariationName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[InternalCode] AS [InternalCode], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ManufacturerProductCode] AS 
[ManufacturerProductCode], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ManufacturerName] AS [ManufacturerName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[Ean] AS [Ean], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductCategoryName] AS 
[ProductCategoryName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[RatecardId] AS [RatecardId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[RatecardName] AS [RatecardName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ClientName] AS [ClientName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[AccountCode] AS [AccountCode], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductRatecardGroupName] AS 
[ProductRatecardGroupName]
FROM [dbo].[vClientActiveRatecardPrice] AS [vClientActiveRatecardPrice]) 
AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[ClientId] = @p__linq__0) AND (([Extent1].[ProductCompound] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[ProductCompound] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0=2065,@p__linq__1='12_0'
```

My manual SQL is as follows:

```
select * from vClientActiveRatecardPrice where ClientId = 2065 and ProductCompound = '12_0'
```

I am at a loss to see what else I could be doing here, to improve the performance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: slow in the app fast in SSMS?  http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html you may have a parameter sniffing issue.

Comment: Hi Nick, I do not think it is that as the code I run from the EF generated SQL takes the same time.  The code generated in question has over 400,000 reads where as my manual query has 8268 reads.

Comment: The EF query is different. It has an OR in it to allow for NULLS. They are different queries.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following code:

```
                vClientActiveRatecardPrice activeRatecardPrice = cckentities.vClientActiveRatecardPrices.Where(p => p.ClientId == clientId && p.ProductCompound == productCompound).First();
```

To:

```
                var activeRatecardPrice = cckentities.vClientActiveRatecardPrices.Where(p => p.ClientId == clientId && p.ProductCompound == productCompound);
```

And then accessed the first result using:

```
activeRatecardPrice.ToList().First()
```

This has fixed my issue.  The resulting SQL is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[AutoId] AS [AutoId], 
[Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[Extent1].[ProductCompound] AS [ProductCompound], 
[Extent1].[ProductRatecardGroupId] AS [ProductRatecardGroupId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[VariationName] AS [VariationName], 
[Extent1].[InternalCode] AS [InternalCode], 
[Extent1].[ManufacturerProductCode] AS [ManufacturerProductCode], 
[Extent1].[ManufacturerName] AS [ManufacturerName], 
[Extent1].[Ean] AS [Ean], 
[Extent1].[ProductCategoryName] AS [ProductCategoryName], 
[Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
[Extent1].[RatecardId] AS [RatecardId], 
[Extent1].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
[Extent1].[RatecardName] AS [RatecardName], 
[Extent1].[ClientName] AS [ClientName], 
[Extent1].[AccountCode] AS [AccountCode], 
[Extent1].[ProductRatecardGroupName] AS [ProductRatecardGroupName]
FROM (SELECT 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[AutoId] AS [AutoId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductCompound] AS [ProductCompound], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductRatecardGroupId] AS [ProductRatecardGroupId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[Name] AS [Name], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[VariationName] AS [VariationName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[InternalCode] AS [InternalCode], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ManufacturerProductCode] AS [ManufacturerProductCode], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ManufacturerName] AS [ManufacturerName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[Ean] AS [Ean], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductCategoryName] AS [ProductCategoryName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[RatecardId] AS [RatecardId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[RatecardName] AS [RatecardName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ClientName] AS [ClientName], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[AccountCode] AS [AccountCode], 
[vClientActiveRatecardPrice].[ProductRatecardGroupName] AS [ProductRatecardGroupName]
FROM [dbo].[vClientActiveRatecardPrice] AS [vClientActiveRatecardPrice]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[ClientId] = @p__linq__0) AND (([Extent1].[ProductCompound] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[ProductCompound] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0=2065,@p__linq__1='103_0'
```

If I am being honest, I am unsure as to how this solved the problem...

Comment: Because you are returning one row, not 480,000. So now your query is even more different

Comment: Hi Nick.  I was not aware the EF command ".Where" returns all items in the view.  I have some serious work to do now to fix my application...

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you were already using `FirstOrDefault` in your prior code - that's what I was referring to. So, no.... `where` doesn't return all items in the view. The code change you made would be all folded into the same code anyway, but you should really have an `ORDER BY` to guarantee which one comes actually comes first

Comment: This may have made the query faster but it adds a huge amount of overhead to your .NET code. It now has to allocate memory for 480,000 objects and map the columns of 480,000 records into those objects and add them to a List. Then you take the first one and I'm assuming throw out the rest. If you run the original EF-generated SQL, in SSMS, does it run just as slowly? If so, you can compare its execution plan to your manual SQL to try to get a hint. Just guessing it probably has something to do with the nulls part of the where clause or the varchar(8000) it's choosing.

Comment: This may have made the query faster but it adds a huge amount of overhead to your .NET code. It now has to allocate memory for 480,000 objects and map the columns of 480,000 records into those objects and add them to a List. Then you take the first one and I'm assuming throw out the rest. If you run the original EF-generated SQL, in SSMS, does it run just as slowly? If so, you can compare its execution plan to your manual SQL to try to get a hint. Just guessing it probably has something to do with the nulls part of the where clause or the varchar(8000) it's choosing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  If this is adding a huge overhead, which command should I use?  Should I steer clear of '.First' and just stipulate the '.Where' arguments and grab the first result after (and check for null)?

Comment: I suggest you profile the SQL being submitted and understand what's really going on. Both SQL and LINQ will "rewrite" your code to run efficiently. Don't assume that manually rewriting your code makes any difference